# If modern civilization collapsed, what impact would a lack of trade and industrial base have on the next civilization centuries later?

Tags: science-based, post-apocalypse, alternate-earth, empire-building

Let's say that civilization ends due to non-globally destructive means. For instance, a rising tide that destroys ports and trade wouldn't scar the landscape of Denver the way nuclear war would. Economic collapse or riots wouldn't change the climate. Please, nobody mention zombies. The result is people living essentially in anarchy until a new power can come maintain order.

Centuries later, a new civilization begins to rise, but they haven't yet built an industrial base or trade network. Working factories are minimal and there are few comparable civilizations with which a trading relationship could be established. What specific obstacles or resource deficiencies would they most likely face in the first decades of trying to rebuild?

For instance, there would likely be plenty of aluminum from recycling to eliminate the need for mining more in the short-term, but the civilization would not likely have access to citrus unless it was within a citrus growing region. The civilization would not be able to build new skyscrapers, but it would be able to make passable replacement glass for windows at high cost.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to understand what kind of questions we answer here: well defined problems, with a single question per post and that can be objectively measured.

Comment: This is a very broad question, are you able to narrow it down a bit? maybe state what you think would be practical to salvage and then ask if thats correct, and if not then what is. as at this time this question is likely to get put on hold as either too broad or too opinion based...

Comment: There's a mismatch within the question which makes a proper answer really awkward even if the question wasn't otherwise too broad: "modern knowledge, but no trade network or strong industrial base" you couldn't keep that full knowledge base _without being able to use it_.

Comment: I'll refine the question to improve it.

Comment: The real problem for future generations will be that resources have been spread out.. and don't exist in concentrated areas anymore... Gathering copper for example will be difficult.

Comment: "Centuries" can be a really, really long time in politics, economics, and technological development. There seems no need to 'rebuild' old (industrial) infrastructure - new infrastructure will be built when and where it is needed...as it always has been.

Comment: It's more of a problem of production chains. If you have a saw and a pickaxe, it's easier to make the next saw and pickaxe. If you have an industrial fabrication machine, you can make another one. This kind of gap, once it spans all industry, can't be built in a matter of decades.

Comment: As @Amadeus says, the collapse of modern civilization would be undone in about a century, undetectable outside of history books in 500 years, and a subject only for academic study in 1000 years.

Comment: As I read your conditions, I find that your query's basic premise is seriously flawed. I see no reason why, for example, American civilisation should be destroyed simply because the coasts are indundated. On the contrary, many would agree that a general cleansing of DC, NYC and the Left Coast would be a Very Good Thing indeed. Trade networks that depend on *ships* will indeed be disrupted. But the US can continue to trade very easily with Canada and Mexico simply because of rail and road networks. Eurasia can get along very nicely as well... (cont)

Comment: (concl.) ... And what will prevent the US from simply bulldozing a path through the wreckage and reopening old ports? Or establishing new ones? China, Japan, Korea, Australia and the EU will certainly do the same. I think a general rethink of your query is in order!

Comment: Also, we could continue to trade with Europe & Asia simply because of *Airports*!

Comment: If the next civilization is centuries later, they will be developing their own trade networks and production chains as they develop, not relying on old, unmaintained equipment.

Comment: Production *chains* are changing all the time already, and look completely different in 2018 from the nation-based supply chains of 1968, so there is more resiliency than the premise assumes. Most of the knowledge to rebuild everything before about 1990 was printed in books and (still) stored in tens of thousands of libraries. Previous collapse/apocalyspe-without-zombies questions on this site have a consensus of about 50-100 years to resume modern standards of living. People *like* having air conditioning and cars and phones, and will want them back.

Comment: @elemtilas, You're not factoring in that air-based trade is prohibitively expensive or that pan-american trade has the same political conditions as global trade.

Comment: @user535733, you're exactly right. If we assume a period of destabilization and anarchy before civilization begins being restored, this question is about that first few decades when they're not there yet.

Comment: Comments are intended to help you refine and edit your question. The question currently specifies centuries, not one or two decades.

Comment: @TravisKindred --- You don't leave a choice! Just because a big old tide gums up the ports doesn't mean civilisation is going to collapse and doesn't mean people in Kansas and West Virginia aren't going to keep wanting to shop at Wall Mart! Until the ports get cleared & rebuilt (or new ones built), trade will simply use what it's got. Hence: faulty premise!

Comment: @user535733, True. I've made adjustments to clarify that point.

Comment: @elemtilas, air transportation is roughly 5x the cost of sea transportation, and that's before factoring in the increased demand for pilots and insufficient air-trade capacity. Unleaded gas/diesel for instance would cost double or triple what it does now. When gas/diesel increases, everything increases. When basic goods cost 2-3x overnight, the strain on the poor becomes too much to bear and social unrest can take over.

Comment: We keep going in circles here: basic premise is faulty. A little bit of "social unrest" because goods *imported from Eurasia* cost more does not in any way equate to the destruction of civilisation. A natural disaster that wipes out the outer / coastal ring of a few miles of a continent does not equate to the destruction of civilisation. Keep in mind: between Canada, USA & Mexico; Central America & South America --- all connected by rail and roads --- there is more than enough petroleum, food production, man power, manufacturing capacity & money to survive intact until the crisis is solved.

Comment: So what if we can't trade with China to the same degree we did before? And that's just the economics. Socially, I think you far underestimate the USA at least. If you're old enough to remember the events of 11 Sept 2001, or are old enough to remember WWII, you will know that the American people will simply assault the problem until it gets solved. A natural disaster of this sort will be cleared within a year or two. Look for new & improved coastal cities, ports and coastal infrastructure built bigger & better within 10 years.

Answer (score 3):

That's a lot of questions, but essentially, the main dividing line between the "old west" and modern society revolves around electricity, and although the electric light bulb was invented in 1879, we did not reach half of American homes with electric lights until 1925. Less than 100 years ago!

Radio only began to be a major force in the 1920's, Television in the 1950's.

The ramp-up of those technologies to the current state was delayed because they were ***new inventions,*** so given your "modern knowledge" allowance, we can imagine they would be re-deployed **very** rapidly, in a matter of decades. Same with engines, running on gasoline, coal, steam, etc. Because everybody **already knows** the value of these technologies.

And to an extent the same with computers. If the electricity has been off, computer chips don't exactly "rot", in mild climates (not overly hot or freezing to cause thermal expansion and contraction stress) they should survive just fine.

Also, remember international trade existed centuries before even the steam engine was invented, even before America was invented. There is no reason to think it should suddenly stop. Given "modern knowledge" again, wooden sailing ships are not that hard to build, and back in the 1700s and 1800s, trade routes were a good way to get wealthy; by the law of supply and demand, at first. Being one of the few ships to visit a port, there was not a lot of supply for what the captain brought to sell (so his markup was high), and not a lot of options to sell what you had overseas (so he could buy relatively low). I should think this is an opportunity many would seize, get 50 men together to build a boat and find their fortunes. Again, unlike the men of 500 years ago, with modern knowledge every major problem in navigation, materials, and management is already solved.

I do not think the industrial base would be difficult to rebuild after centuries of abandonment: Basically we built it up in about 75 years, *without knowing exactly what we were doing* and still having to invent new parts of it along the way. If we know pretty much exactly what to do and what to work on, it should get rebuilt in perhaps fifty years, certainly not *longer* than 75 years.

Comment: Perspective: When my mother was a child, the last of the participants in the gunfight at the OK corral was still alive. Wyatt Earp's grand children are still kicking around today.